# Origin of “up and at ’em”

Tags: etymology, expressions

The phrase `up and at ’em` (commonly construed as `?up and Adam`) is used a lot. Where did it originate?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a contraction and conflation of two orders *Get Up!* (meaning 'stand and prepare') and *Get At Them!* (meaning 'attack them'). The *and* is narrative, meaning 'and then'.

Both of these *get*'s are causative/inchoative senses of *be*, and therefore phrases like *be up* and *be at them* also exist. The rest is just idiom formation, and occasionally spelling confusion and eggcorn creation.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase is "up and at 'em" or more accurately "up and at them". According to the [Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/11/messages/689.html), it probably comes from the military with the full command being "Up, Guards, and at 'em!"

Comment: That quotation is from Wellngton at Waterloo, but I find it hard to believe the phrase wasn't in use earlier.

Answer (score 1):

We use this phrase a lot in Newfoundland where most of our people originated in Ireland. We use the phase as a way to say “get up and start working/moving”.